# Problema al crear Conexión con MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, ireport

Me aparece

> SQL problems: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigInteger
>   cannot be cast to java.lang.Long

Al hacer click en Test.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Qué versión de Connector/J está usando?.

Answer (score 1):

Si estás usando por defecto el driver de NetBeans para conectar a la BBDD MySQL, te recomiendo que descargues el conector actualizado desde: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/8.0.html
Y lo añadas a tu proyecto como un EXTERNAL JAR. Este error lo he leído tiempo hace en otros portales y mayormente se soluciona cambiando el conector.